# How to improve google speech recognition performance with pre-process

Tags: google-cloud-speech

When I try google speech recognition it shows low performance on traditional Chineses audio file with background noise. Can I improve the performance of speech recognition after some pre-processing(like speech enhancement)? Does it work on google speech service?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you go through [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/best-practices) page in google cloud speech documentation outlining best practices on how to provide speech data to the service, including recommendations for pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the recording as close to the original speech signal as possible. No distortion, no clipping, no noise, no artificial pre-processing, like noise suppression and automatic gain control. I think such kind of pre-processings can damage the useful information in speech signals.

I copied the key points from google and paste them as below.

1. Position the microphone as close as possible to the person that is speaking, particularly when background noise is present.
2. Avoid audio clipping.
3. Do not use automatic gain control (AGC).
4. All noise reduction processing should be disabled.
5. Listen to some sample audio. It should sound clear, without distortion or unexpected noise.